# MySql limit and offset giving wrong result

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, laravel-5

**I'm getting only 99 records for limit 100 after 9900 offset**. Even though i have 2,00,000 records in db with left join in both the tables with distinct. What's wrong with my query or loop

Even i tried the query in **phpmyadmin** there also it was giving same result 99 records.

**Query**

```
select distinct(table1.id), table2.name, table2.uuid from table1
        left join table2 on table1.id = table2.id limit 9900, 100
```

**Laravel Query:**

```
$this
->database
->table('table1')
->selectRaw('distinct(table1.id), table2.uuid, table2.name')
->leftJoin('table1.id', '=', 'table2.id')
->where('opponent_uID', '>', $uID)
->skip($offset)
->take($limit)
->get();
```

**Loop**

```
$limit = 100;
$offset = 0;
while (true) {
     $result = $this->query($limit, $offset);
     $offset += $limit;
     if (empty($result)) {
         break;
     }
     // Logic here
}
```

Comment: Telling us how many records are in your database is a bit meaningless.  More relevant is the number of records in the two tables being joined, and how the left join could increase the possible number of records in the result set.  Also, using `DISTINCT` can affect the number of records.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen 2,00,000 records in both table with left join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be right answer to address why it was giving the 99 records. But i when i play with that query i found these solutions

**Issue:**

1. One main issue with query is i don't have order by.

> MySQL MyISAM tables make no guarantees on result with out order by on
>   limit, offsets

**Solutions:**

1. Using order by in query Giving 100 results but not tested with entire loop

   **select distinct(table1.id), table2.name, table2.uuid from table1 left join table2 on table1.id = table2.id order by table1.id limit 9900, 100**
2. Strangely if i use table2.* instead of some fields in same query with out order by gives 100 records

   **select distinct(table1.id), table2.* from table1 left join table2 on table1.id = table2.id order by table1.id limit 9900, 100**

So, Finally it's only my assumption for the problem is there might chance of null values in left join tables give wrong result.